# How to display classic man page from local file with troff format?

Tags: command-line, file-format, manpage

I have a file with troff format and would like to recast to man page

file.txt:

```
.. c:function:: bool is_module_percpu_address (unsigned long addr)

   test whether address is from module static percpu

**Parameters**

``unsigned long addr``
  address to test

**Description**

Test whether **addr** belongs to module static percpu area.

**Return**

``true`` if **addr** is from module static percpu area


.. c:function:: int module_refcount (struct module * mod)

   return the refcount or -1 if unloading

**Parameters**

``struct module * mod``
  the module we're checking

**Return**

     -1 if the module is in the process of unloading
     otherwise the number of references in the kernel to the module
```

I don't really understand the output of groff, when I do `groff file.txt | man -l -`.

As you can see, I have never done man pages, just want to use a troff format and made it a readable man page.

How to do so?